# Looking for help with knitting machine terms

Tags: translation

I've been trying to un-puzzle the computerized knitting machine instruction in Chinese for my mom, and I've been doing fine until these two appeared:

- 花板
- 起始针

Can't make head or tails of them in this particular sentence:

当起始针+花版最大幅宽大于针床设定总针数时，系统将弹出报警提示.

What are the English equivalents of these two? Especially, 花板?

Comment: users recommend web search for 编织机 (knitting machine),e.g. 针床  needle bed

Comment: https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%AF%9B%E8%A1%A3%E7%BC%96%E7%BB%87%E6%9C%BA e.g describes the home operation (操作) of a knitting machine, find finds many instances of 花样 （although not of 花板),it may serve as abbreviation of, 花板片 pattern-forming card,起始针 = literally, initiating the needle/ starting stitch, roughly: when  maximum width of starting stitch and pattern-forming card  is above the overall stitch number set by the needle bed, the system will pop up a warning signal

Answer (score 1):

This is my understanding of the terms:

起始针 - starting stitches (the first row)

花样 - pattern

花板 - most likely pattern template

花版最大幅 - the largest (widest) part of the pattern template

设定总针数 - pre-set total number of stitches

The sentence you quote sounds like an awkward translation of the following:

When the number of stitches at starting + stitches at largest part of the pattern exceeds the total number pre-set by the knitting bed, a warning signal will pop up.

Now I have to admit I've never used a knitting machine before, but I have been knitting since I was nine years old, so I feel I can probably shed some light on this. It makes sense that a machine will need to have a limit on how big a garment and how complicated a pattern it can produce. If my understanding is correct, you probably don't need to worry about this part, unless you're trying to knit something really, really enormous or have an extraordinarily complex pattern.

Answer (score 0):

花板 = Flower board

means pattern area, draw the pattern here or draw the pattern in this area.

起始针 = Starting needle

The first needle that knits for this pattern.

当起始针+花版最大幅宽大于针床设定总针数时，系统将弹出报警提示. = When the starting needle+flower version of the most large width than the needle bed set the total number of stitches, the system will pop up alarm.

When the widest part of the pattern plus the position of the first needle exceeds the number of needles in the needle bed, the pattern is too wide to knit warning is triggered. Move the starting needle to the left or make the pattern narrower to fit the available needles.

Hope that helps.